# Give back parents per children

Tags: xpath

I have a XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  </book>

  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  </book>

  <book category="it" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>

</bookstore>
```

When I evaluate the XPATH
    /bookstore/book/author/parent::book

I get the result:

```
/bookstore[1]/book[1]
/bookstore[1]/book[2]
```

But as the second  has three -nodes I am searching for a XPATH expression that gives me back the following:

```
/bookstore[1]/book[1]
/bookstore[1]/book[2]
/bookstore[1]/book[2]
/bookstore[1]/book[2]
```

Is this possible?

Thanks
Regards
Mario

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, the XPATH

```
//author!parent::book/path()
```

returns:

```
/Q{}bookstore[1]/Q{}book[2]
/Q{}bookstore[1]/Q{}book[2]
/Q{}bookstore[1]/Q{}book[2]
/Q{}bookstore[1]/Q{}book[2]
```

Thanks
Regards
Mario